# Determine if an int is a palindrome in Java?

Tags: java

I was working on a problem on LeetCode that asks the question: determine whether an integer is a palindrome without converting the integer into a string. I am able to come up with my own algorithm to determine a palindrome but couldn't come up with one without converting the integer to a string. So I ran into this code on the Internet:

```
public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
    if (x < 0)
        return false;

    // initialize how many zeros
    int div = 1;
    while (x / div >= 10) {
        div = div * 10;
    }

    while (x != 0) {
        int left = x / div;
        int right = x % 10;

        if (left != right)
            return false;

        x = (x % div) / 10;
        div = div / 100;
    }   
    return true;
}
```

I step through the code several times to see what it was doing but I am having such a hard time understanding how this person was able to come up with this logic. Now, I know how division and modulo works. However, this part is fuzzy:

```
// initialize how many zeros
int div = 1;
while (x / div >= 10) {
    div = div * 10;
}
```

I believe this person is trying to determine the decimal place?

The next snippet part of their code, I'm completely baffled as to how they came up with this. I mean ... is this some simple math trick that I'm obviously not coming up with an explanation? In simple terms, what are they doing here? How did they decide on the divisor of 10 and 100?

```
x = (x % div) / 10;
div = div / 100;
```

I appreciate any explanation to help me understand. Thanks in Advance.

v/r,

Allen

Comment: This might work better on Code Review.  That being said, the mod and division tricks here are just being used to isolate individual digits from the number.  The code snippet you posted, I would assume, is then comparing individual digits on either side of the pivot to make sure they are the same.

Comment: If you have an integer, there is no decimal place. Try writing down a few example numbers and going over the algorithm

Comment: not searching decimal place, just change the comment to `// initialize how many digits` (or divisor needed to separate the first digit)

Answer (score 2):

Let's take x=12321

Then

```
int div = 1;
while (x / div >= 10) {
    div = div * 10;
}
```

above part makes div = 10000,

then this part makes left = 1 and right = 1, and then left and right are compared

```
int left = x / div;
int right = x % 10;
```

Then, as we move through this part

```
x = (x % div) / 10;
div = div / 100;
```

this occurs

```
x = (12321%10000)/10 = (2321)/10 = 232
```

They modulo with div, to get rid of the first digit and then they divide by 10 to remove the last digit. The first and the last digits are removed because they have already been compared. The div is divided by 100, because we remove 2 digits from 'x' at a time...the first digit and the last digit.

```
now, x = 232
```

This part makes left = 2 and right = 2, and again left and right are compared

```
int left = x / div;
int right = x % 10;
```

then, as we move through this part

```
x = (x % div) / 10;
div = div / 100;
```

this occurs

```
x = (232%100)/10 = (32)/10 = 3
```

After this, left = 3 and right = 3, they match, 'true' is returned and the loop ends.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
    int temp = number;
    int result = 0;
    while (temp != 0) {
        result = result * 10 + temp % 10;
        temp /= 10;
    }
    return number == result;
}
```